# Parallelize recursive code using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

how can I parallelize following code using python multiprocessing

```
def func(a,i):
   if (a>i):
      func(a-1,i)
      func(a-5,i)
   else :
      print a
```

EDIT : Is it true that once parent process exits, all child subprocesses also exit?

EDIT 2 :

I have implemented following code but it is not working. can you please find the error.

```
p=[]
def func(a,i):
 if a>i :
   proc=Process(target=func,args=(a-1,i,))
   p.append(proc)
   proc=Process(target=func,args=(a-5,i,))
   p.append(proc)

 else :
   print a

if _name_=='_main_':
   proc=Process(target=func,args=(100,25,))
   p.append(proc)
   for x in p:
     x.start()
     x.join()
```

Above code is executing only for (100,25) and not for subprocesses even though the subprocesses are getting added in list.

Comment: Why do you want to parallelize this? Is it slow? Or for educational reasons?

Comment: Have you used Python's Multiprocessing library before? Is your question a general query about how to use the library? Or are you wondering if it's safe to parallelize a recursive function?

Comment: Does the order in which the results are printed matter?

Comment: I want to learn to implement library for recursive calls. The order of results does not matter.

Comment: The processes do not share `p`, therefore your code only starts one subprocess. I suggest you look for an approach where you use a queue instead of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

The variables assigned at the starting of the code don't have value remained in a function, so you need to add global to the function before its use in the function.
Change your code to:

```
p=[]
def func(a,i):
    global p
    if a>i :
        proc=Process(target=func,args=(a-1,i,))
        p.append(proc)
        proc=Process(target=func,args=(a-5,i,))
        p.append(proc)


    else :
        print a

if _name_=='_main_':
   global p
   proc=Process(target=func,args=(100,25,))
   p.append(proc)
   for x in p:
     x.start()
     x.join()
```